# SQL complex query using Group By

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a table like

```
Product Id   Status          Date
1            Ordered         01/02/1999
1            Leased          02/04/2001
1            SubLeased       12/31/2000
1            Cancelled       10/25/2003
```

I need to display all the records and also a max(date) for that product in a single query.
Result should be like

```
ProductId    Status          Date          Max(date)
1            Ordered         01/02/1999    10/25/2003
1            Leased          02/04/2001    10/25/2003
1            SubLeased       12/31/2000    10/25/2003
1            Cancelled       10/25/2003    10/25/2003
```

Comment: correlated subquery or cross join or analytic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL2005+: I would use MAX aggregate function with [OVER clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  t.ProductId, t.Status, t.Date, 
        MAX(t.Date) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ProductId) AS MaxPerProductId
FROM    MySchema.MyTable AS t
```

Example:

```
SELECT  o.object_id, o.name, o.create_date,
        MAX(o.create_date) OVER() AS MaxCreateDate
FROM    sys.objects o
ORDER BY o.create_date DESC;
```

Results:

```
object_id   name                 create_date             MaxCreateDate
----------- -------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
448720651   Persons              2013-10-19 22:29:37.503 2013-10-19 22:29:37.503
432720594   PK_Invoice_InvoiceID 2013-10-13 21:16:28.287 2013-10-19 22:29:37.503
416720537   Invoice              2013-10-13 21:16:26.560 2013-10-19 22:29:37.503
256719967   MyTable              2013-10-12 23:34:34.260 2013-10-19 22:29:37.503
224719853   spTest               2013-10-03 22:47:50.380 2013-10-19 22:29:37.503
...
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But I need this max date based on Product Id. I mean max date for each seprate product

Comment: @Gudiya: Then you need `PARTITION BY`: `MAX(t.Date) OVER(PARTITION BY t.ProductId) AS MaxPerProductId`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

if mysql is like below statement, you can reference,

```
SELECT act.*,(SELECT MAX(a.create_date) maxtime FROM table a) FROM table act ;
```